# GeoTools and image storage / retrieval

Tags: geotools, image

Please can someone let me know how I can create a schema (using `SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder()`), read and write image data? Simple data types (Integer/Float etc) work fine but how do I handle image data?

Answer (score 1):

SimpleFeatures are used for Vector data, for images you will need a coverage reader. See the [image tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/raster/image.html) for a good introduction.

Comment: Hi @iant, Thank you very much for responding to my question, it is really appreciated. I realised that I have posed my question incorrectly though and wondered if I could rephrase it? Although it is image data that I'd like to store, it is generally just binary data and I was wondering if it is possible to store bytea type data as simple feature data? Thank you! Martin...